# Status bar on web app from home screen when full-screen

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have got a web page that I am showing on full-screen when open it from the home screen via:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

this works fine, but in iOS7 the status bar appears with a black text over black background and:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

does not work, while it works on iOS8.

Where does it get the text colour? and why there is no possible way to change it? I searched for a bit on this matter and I couldn't find a solution other than not showing the app on full-screen mode, I need to show the time on the status bar.